# UISearchBar cancel button Xcode 4.3?

Tags: iphone, uisearchbar, xcode4.3, cancel-button

How do I get the cancel button to only appear when the user starts entering text into the UISearchBar?

I tried this

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)aSearchBar {
self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
}
```

But it doesn't work, I don't think there's anything wrong with with setting it to "showsCancelButton" because even when I say

`NSLog(@"Typing");`

It won't print out to the screen. Is there another method in Xcode 4.3 that can do this?
Is there also a method that knows if the cancel button has been pressed?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the class is the delegate of `searchBar`? Try setting `self.searchBar.delegate=self;` in the `viewDidLoad` method.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is not returning a BOOLean value, 'YES.'  This should work:

```
// show search bar's cancel button when editing
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

    searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;

    return YES;
}
// hide search bar's cancel button when not editing
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

    searchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)aSearchBar {
  aSearchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
}
```